# Left join with multiple matches on right table with conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to do a SQL Server query where in my left table (database 1 - Db1), I have some Data that need to be checked some times.
I can`t write in this table (Db1, read only) so I have created other database Db2 that when I check the information related to some record in Db1, I save the date of this check at Db2.
Then, I have a list on the left table that shows me all the records that have to be check. When I create the check record in db2, for some time, 3-4 month,  the list does not have to show me this record again.
So the query must handle that, if there is not record in db2, if is null, the record must be showed in the list, then if I create one check, for a time (3-4 month) does not have to show this record, when the 3-4 months have passed, the record have to be again in the list to remember to do a new check, then if I create a new check in Db2 with new date, the record at left has to hide again for 3-4 month more and so on.

I have tried this, that works if there is only one record at Db2, but as soon as I create another check, the old record, the first one, does not allow to hide the left record on the list.

I hope some one can give me a clue.

Thank you in advance

```
SELECT uno.fecha_ini, uno.fecha_res, uno.fecha_fin, uno.n_contrato, uno.n_propied, tres.n_contrato
FROM [GI].[dbo].[alq03] uno
LEFT JOIN [GI_impuestos].[dbo].[checkar] tres ON uno.n_contrato = tres.n_contrato
WHERE tres.n_contrato IS NULL
/*checks*/
AND (tres.fecha_checkar IS NULL)
OR (tres.fecha_checkar NOT BETWEEN (GETDATE() - 120) AND (GETDATE()))
GROUP BY uno.fecha_ini, uno.fecha_res, uno.fecha_fin, uno.n_contrato, uno.n_propied, tres.n_contrato
ORDER BY uno.fecha_fin asc
```

Comment: It'll be much easier to answer your question if you provide the table definitions and some sample data (within the question, as text - not images). Feel free to also use tools like http://sqlfiddle.com/ and https://dbfiddle.uk/ to share your schema

Comment: 1) You have both an `AND` and an `OR` - to ensure these work correctly I expect you need brackets. 2) The way `NOT BETWEEN` works is not always straight forward - have you checked with the docs that this does what you require. 3) `GETDATE() -120` means what? While SQL Server allows this, who knows what it does, you should use the provided datetime functions e.g. `DATEADD()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of what you are asking for. You will have to modify it to suit your needs.

> ```
> create table readOnly(
> id int primary key,
> info varchar(100) not null);
> ```

> ```
> insert into readOnly values
> (1,'info to check'),
> (2,'more info'),
> (3,'not finished yet!');
> ```

> ```
> create table chk (
> rid int primary key,
> checked date);
> ```

> ```
> insert into chk values
> (1,'2021-07-01'),
> (2,'2021-12-01')
> ```

> ```
> select 
>    id,
>    coalesce(cast(checked as char),'never') last_check,
>    info info_to_check
> from
>    readOnly
> left join
>    chk on id = rid
> where 
>    datediff(m,checked,getdate())>4
>    or checked is null
> ```

> ```
> id | last_check   | info_to_check           
> -: | :----------- | :----------------
>  1 | 2021-07-01   | info to check    
>  3 | never        | not finished yet!
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0f088d150adc33ca568ef3655895720c)*